# Resizing Wpf Content When a Noresize/Canminimize Window Is Relatively Resized on Different Screens

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF window with a fixed size when showing it on other screen with lower resolution its height become out of desktop area.

I came up with this way in order to get around this issue: Is this a good way to achieve that or there is a better one?

**Window.xaml**

```
        Loaded="Window_Loaded" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Width="1250" Height="750" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

        <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="GridTrans"/>
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <!--Content-->
        </Grid>
```

**Window.xaml.cs**

```
        public MyWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            double OldHeight = Height;
            double OldWidth = Width;
            double AspectRatio = Width / Height;

            Height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * 0.87;
            Width = Height * AspectRatio;

            GridTrans.ScaleY = Height / OldHeight;
            GridTrans.ScaleX = Width / OldWidth;
        }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Calculate the Ratio (Calculated Once) => 0.87
            MessageBox.Show((ActualHeight / SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight).ToString());
        }
```

Comment: this question asks for a personal opinion, so here is mine:
if the information does not fit the screen scaling it is the least favorable option. get scrolviewer in the mix thal will allow you to get more content in a limited space. ofc this higly depends on you application if you are programming the terminal for a nuclear fusion plant it might make sense that you cannot "scrol away" the emergency light display panel...

Comment: Why it's the least favorable option for you? does it affect the resolution of the app? I don't think so! I don't like to use scrollviewers on this app. I want everything to right there in front of the user without scrolling.

Comment: Resiszing any kind of font etc. is a no go if you ask me rendering the application unreadable on small devices in worst case, but if you made your decision already, then no need to ask :)
Generel rule of thumb: if you are doing something nobody else does, its usually not the best aproach. I have never used an application that resized by literally scaling everything down. When you make a button a specific size this has a reason (normally) and scaling it will make it not meet this criteria anymore.
A program wit a proper layout will normally be able to work on small and big screens a like.

Comment: for proper feedback drop a screenshot of your application in your question so people can suggest different approaches for your design

Comment: I agree with you. but there is a point which is the app looks bigger on displays with lower resolution (not with smaller size! as both have the same size).the app looks great on a 15" display which is standard now in many cases. it will look smaller if the display for example was 14".but will look great on any other screen whatever the resolution it has.I don't want to use scroll bar as the user have a display with lower resolution with the same size as mine.if there is a solution for this I can start implement scrollviewers in my app and stop using scaling to keep the user experience the same

Comment: Whle i still think its a bad idea consider just using a viewbox, it does all that autmoatically and scales your content to the window size